# ionic 2 Geolocation clearWatch or unsubscribe

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation, ionic2, cordova-plugins

So I'm working with Google Maps and Ionic 2. Cordova has a plugin for retrieving user's geolocation, and I have two questions about the plugin.

But before I state my questions, here's my code

```
import { Geolocation } from 'ionic-native';

watchPosition(marker) {
    let watch = Geolocation.watchPosition({
        //enableHighAccuracy: true
    });

    watch.subscribe((pos) => {
        marker.setPosition({
            lat: pos.coords.latitude,
            lng: pos.coords.longitude
        });
    });

    // stop watching if the user starts dragging the map
    this.map.addListener('dragstart', () => {
        // There might be two ways to do this, but non of them works
        watch.unsubscribe();
        Geolocation.clearWatch(watch);
    });
}
```

1. AFAIK, there are two ways to stop watching the user's location: `watch.unsubscribe()` and `Geolocation.clearWatch(watch)`. However, I have no clue what's the difference besides `unsubscribe` has the type of `Observable` and the other is imported from the `Geolocation` plugin. Which one should I use?
2. The above question is actually trivial, the most importent problem I have now is that neither of them works. `watch.unsubscribe()` give the error that `[ts] Property 'unsubscribe' does not exist on type 'Observable<Geoposition>'.` and `Geolocation.clearWatch(watch)` gives me `[ts] Property 'clearWatch' does not exist on type 'typeof Geolocation'.` Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [Ionic Native Typescript wrapper](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/blob/master/src/%40ionic-native/plugins/geolocation/index.ts) for the [geolocation plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation), you can see that:

- it does not expose the `clearWatch()` function directly
- [its `watchPosition()` wrapper](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/blob/master/src/%40ionic-native/plugins/geolocation/index.ts#L189) returns an Observable whose `unsubscribe()` action is to call `clearWatch()` on the geolocation plugin with the internal `watchId`. Hence the Ionic Native way to clear the watch is to call `unsubscribe()` on the Observable returned by `Geolocation.watchPosition()`.

However, if for some reason that's not working, you could just call the plugin API directly:

```
declare var navigator: any;

// Add watch
let watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
    // do something with position
} , (error) => {
    // do something with error
}), options);

// Clear watch
navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchId);
```

Comment: Thanks! That answers my questions. BTW, I think you meant `clearWatch(watchId)` on the last line.

Comment: What do we do when there is no unsubcsribe method to the observable returned by ionic's geolocation watchPosition?

Answer (score 3):

Even if it is a little late...

- watchPosition() returns an Observable
- you can subscribe to this Observable
- the subscribe() call returns a Subscription
- from the Subscription, you can unsubscribe()

Putting it all together:

```
let subscription = this.geolocation.watchPosition().subscribe(
    (position) => { ... },
);

...

subscription.unsubscribe();
```